# how to set host application for a dll

Tags: visual-c++

I have a sample dll and an application which uses this dll in Visual C++ 2010 Express. They are working. Now I want to change the application to a delphi application and debug the dll in Visual C++.
How to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the DLL project properties window and go to the Debugging page. Enter the file path/name of the delphi exe at "Command"